# FIWARE - Orion LD offset parameter does not provide any results after threshold

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am using FIWARE Orion-LD in order to store Social Media posts, whose number exceeds 300,000.

I would like to access all the entities of type SMPost which belong to a specific SMCollection.

`GET <orion_host>:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entities?options=keyValues&q=belongsToCollection==%22urn:ngsi-ld:SMCollection:XX%22&type=SMPost&limit=1000&offset=XXX&options=count`

For this purpose, I am employing pagination, as instructed in the official documentation, using the parameters limit and offset. Using the parameter options=count, I confirm that indeed all the entities are correctly inserted in the MongoDB.

Everything goes well until the offset is set to 34000, then, when exceeded, an empty list is returned, as a response.

Is this a known issue?  Could you please provide an alternative way that I could get this data?

Thank you very much in advance for your response.

Comment: Moreover, another issue is that when using the parameter orderBy to sort the results using for instance the postId, the response I get is :{
    "type": "https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/errors/BadRequestData",
    "title": "Unknown URI parameter",
    "detail": "orderBy"
}
Even though in the documentation, it is instructed to do so. Could you please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I can see no mention of `orderBy` as a parameter in the latest [NGSI-LD 1.4.2](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/CIM/001_099/009/01.04.02_60/gs_cim009v010402p.pdf) specification - where did you find that parameter?

Comment: "Everything goes well until the offset is set to 34000" ... ok, noted, we (the Orion-LD development team will take a look)

Comment: So, a quick test was done and it worked like a charm - created 35000 entities and then did the query with '?offset=34000'.
HOWEVER, I got 1000 entities back. The 'limit' is supposed to be set to 20 by default but ... that seems to have been broken, need to fix that.

Comment: As a workaround, try adding "&limit=20" or something, the smaller the better, and see what happens - then increase the limit. I have very small entities (one single small attribute). What you have encountered might be a problem with too big response buffer or something similar - will look into that, of course

Comment: @JasonFox thank you very much for your comment. In the Developer Guide (link https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/wiki/download/attachments/82773747/Orion-LD%20-%20Developer%20Guide.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1615372558591&api=v2) the following is written: In Alpha Release 1, Orion-LD reuses the pagination of Orion. Please see the documentation of pagination of Orion for more info. There, I saw the parameter orderBy. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @kzangeli I would like to thank the whole team for the valuable support. I have tried with different limit sizes (from 1 to 1000, as a trial and error approach) and unfortunately, still doesn't work. One idea why it might be the case is the fact that the entities are created by batches (of 100, but tried inserting them one by one as well) so the creation time is identical (?). Could it be that this causes the issue? That's why I wanted to try ordering with another attribute (e.g. postId), which is not possible finally as Jason mentioned.

Comment: @kzangeli please in order to replicate the issue, could you try creating 280,000 entities and then use the query with the offset set to 35,000. (until 34,000 it works fine). Thank you again so much for the support and the patience! :)

Comment: I believe I fixed the issue yesterday, forgot to post here, sorry ...  Just make sure you use the latest orionld docker image on dockerhub.

Comment: Also, did you try using the limit=20 URL parameter?      

If it still fails (with the newest docker image, from yesterday - 0.8-PRE-194), then please post a bug report on Orion-LD's github, with all the info on the entities you are creating.

Comment: Dear kzangeli, thank you for the update. I am currently using the latest orionld docker image. Moreover, I did try the limit=20 parameter (I see that now it returns correctly the number set by the user), unfortunately it still fails. I think what I failed to transmit is the fact that I have 280,000 entities of type SMPost (from social media smart model) and not 34,000. Then, when using the offset 35,000 with limit=20, it gives me an empty response. could you try replicating the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the issue was the lack of indexing in the mongodb for the attribute creDate.
After adding the appropriate index, the problem was solved.
Thank you for the support!